# Ajax not posting in laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#mainmenu').change(function(){
         var main_menu_id = $('#mainmenu').val();

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/sub',
             data: {"main_menu_id": main_menu_id,_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
             success: function (data) {


var submenus = data.submenus;
      for(var i=0; i<submenus.length; i++){
      $('#submenu').append('<option>'+submenus[i]+'</option>');
    }   

          },
             error: function () {
                 alert('what ever');
             }
         }); 
     });
</script>
```

My route

```
Route::post('/sub','TicketController@sub');
```

And my controller

```
public function sub(Request $request)
{    
    dd($request->all());
    return Response([
        'submenus' => DB::connection("mysql2")->table('applicationsubmenu')
        ->join('applicationmenu', 'applicationmenu.Id', '=', 
        'applicationsubmenu.ApplicationMenuId')
        ->select('applicationsubmenu.*')
        ->where('applicationmenu.MainMenuId', '=', $request->main_menu_id)
        ->get()->toarray(), 
    ]);
}
```

I am trying to populate an option submenu from depending from user option menu selection.To do that I tried building an ajax but it seems not to work at all.Neither the laravel function seems to be called at all!

Comment: Is your ajax function succeeding or erroring? That is, which alert is being displayed?

Comment: @NathanHinchey how can I make it so that the value gets updated because if I select one main menu its values remain in the submenu

Comment: I'm asking a much more basic question -- when you run this ajax function you displayed, which alert happens? Is your ajax call even succeeding?

Comment: First of all need to clear the options object from the select, and after of that you need to append the data, if you want to "select" some option need to set the atributte and next need to trigger the change property.

Comment: now its @NathanHinchey working as I wanted,only if I select a menu its values remain in the submenu,they do not get refreshed

Comment: @UlyssesMarx how do I do that?

Comment: need to edit your question to know more about what you want

Comment: simply refresh the selected element @UlyssesMarx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to setup the ajax requests on the project properly:

**In header**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**In script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: replace on the change function var main_menu_id = $('#mainmenu').val(); with $(this).val(); and put it inside of console.log($(this).val()); open your debugger and make the change to ensure that actually your function works.

Comment: now it works but how can I make it so that everytime the select oprion is selected the values in the submenu select update

Comment: maybe with : `$('#select').removeAttr('selected').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');` or `$(mySelect).selectmenu("refresh")`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you dumping the `$request` in your controller?

```
 dd($request->all());
```

Laravel docs:
The dd function dumps the given variables and **ends execution of the script** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-dd

Also when getting values from $request... you are doing this:

```
->where('applicationmenu.MainMenuId', '=', $request->main_menu_id)
```

but you should get the values like this:

```
->where('applicationmenu.MainMenuId', '=', $request->input('main_menu_id')
```

or if you want an array of request then you should set first:

```
$input = $request->all();
```

and then call the value like this:

```
$input->main_menu_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use ajax middleware

```
Route::post('/sub','TicketController@sub')->middleware('ajax');;
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to send the token

```
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/sub',
         data: {'_token':'{{csrf_token()}}',"main_menu_id": main_menu_id},
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
         },
         error: function () {
             alert('what ever');
         }
     });
```